# In WPF, What is the best way to create toolbar buttons so that the images are properly scaled?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, user-interface, icons, toolbar

Specifically, I'm looking to use the 16*16 32-bit png images included with the VS2008ImageLibrary. I've tried manually setting the Height and Width attributes of the image, adjusting margins and padding, adjusting Stretch and RenderOptions. My attempts to create toolbar buttons have all led to either Improper Scaling (blurry icons), the bottom row of pixels on the icon being truncated, or the toolbar button being improperly sized - not to mention the disappearing icons already mentioned [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/684324/disappearing-icons-in-wpf). Has anyone found the best way to make standard, VisualStudio/WinForms-style toolbar buttons that display properly in WPF?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, change the image resolution to 96DPI, this can done with the free Paint.net ( http://www.getpaint.net ) by opening the file, Selecting Image->Canvas Size from the menu and adjusting the "resolution" to 96 and saving.

If this doesn't help you can then use the solution I wrote about in my blog here http://www.nbdtech.com/blog/archive/2008/11/20/blurred-images-in-wpf.aspx

Comment: Thanks! Adjusting the resolution greatly simplified the code. The issue with the button truncating the image at 15 pixels seems to have miraculously disappeared on its own, even for non-96DPI images, though.

Answer (score 3):

Best way would be using Vector graphics instead of png. I know the following is not exactly what you asked for, but imho there is no way for better looking icons. Also it would help you get rid off margins and paddings. (Ok, if you want to use photos you're screwed)

Bad News is you probably need to repaint all your icons. You could do this using MS Expression Blend(it's capable to save painted Images as .xaml) or you make them on our own with a texteditor. 
I prefer the Border.Background instead of the Image.Source for placing the icon, this allows me to put text over the image. This would look samething like that:

```
<Window.Resources>
   <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/Icons.xaml"/>
</Window.Resources>
<!--
...
-->
<Button>
   <Border Background="{StaticResource IconName}" Height="16" Width="16" />
</Button>
```

Answer (score 1):

The best workaround I can come up with is this:

```
<Image x:Key="TB_NewIcon" Source="Toolbar Images/NewDocumentHS.png" Height="16" Width="16" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="NearestNeighbor"/>
...
<Button Command="ApplicationCommands.New" Content="{StaticResource TB_NewIcon}" Padding="2,2,2,1"/>
```

Or Alternatively:

```
<BitmapImage x:Key="TB_NewIcon" UriSource="Toolbar Images\NewDocumentHS.png"/>
...
<Button Command="ApplicationCommands.New" Padding="2,2,2,1">
    <Image Source="{StaticResource TB_NewIcon}" Height="16" Width="16" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="NearestNeighbor"/>
</Button>
```

For the Button Tag, the Padding attribute is needed to ensure that the image isn't truncated at a height of 15 pixels, and that the button isn't resized to fit the image. Alternatively, we could specify Padding="1", but then we must manually set Height="21" and Width="22" to ensure the button isn't resized to fit the image 
On the Image Tab, the Height and Width are needed to ensure that the image isn't stretched. SnapsToDevicePixels and RenderOptions.BitMapScalingMode are both needed to ensure that there is no blurring. I can't promise that this will work nicely for all resolutions.

Note:
For the NewDocumentHS.png icon, the one that causes the most issues,as it takes up the full 16 pixels of height, you may want to adjust the padding to "1,1,3,2", so that the bottom aligns more properly with other icons.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to consider trying a new property available now in **WPF4**.
Leave the `RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode` to *HighQuality* or just don't declare it.

On your root element (i.e. your main window) add this property: **`UseLayoutRounding="True"`**.

A property previously only available in Silverlight has now fixed all Bitmap sizing woes. :)

> ***Please Note -*** a few of the effects layout rounding
>   can have on exact layout:
>
> - width and or height of elements may grow or shrink by at most 1 pixel
> - placement of an object can move by at most 1 pixel
> - centered elements can be vertically or horizontally off center by at most
>     1 pixel

More info found here: http://blogs.msdn.com/text/archive/2009/08/27/layout-rounding.aspx